# How to develop free and pro version of WP8 apps sharing the same code?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to develop free and pro version of WP8 apps sharing the same code?

Is it possible to have multiple targets per project like in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone uses a Try and Buy model.

Basically what you would do is create your full blown app.

Decide what limitations you want in the trial version.

Then when the app starts check to see if the user has purchased the full version or if this is a trial.

When they buy the full version just cache that and then from that point forward give them full access.

Its very easy to do

[Here is the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286402%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)